# Create method with implicit arguments string conversion

Tags: java

I want to implement a **method** in Java that **automatically converts the received object to its string representation** without having to explicitly call `toString`, like `print`/`println` does.

Is it possible, and if so, how?

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
myMethod(obj); // Doesn't work
System.out.print(obj); // Works (why?)

static void myMethod(String str) {
    // Do things
}
```

Comment: `print` is overloaded. You're calling [`print(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#print(java.lang.Object)), not `print(String)`.

Comment: MyObject is not a String I think you mean `static void myMethod(MyObject str)`

Comment: @khelwood that makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look deeper into the `System.out.print` method, you see, that this method is overloaded to also allow an `Object` as method argument. Your method only allows to pass a String and because the Object isn't a String, you can't pass it.

You would have to overload your method too:

```
static void myMethod(Object o) {
    // Do things
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method needs to take an `Object` as a parameter, and then call its `toString` method:

```
static void myMethod(Object obj) {
    String stringRepresentation = obj.toString();
    // now work with stringRepresentation
}
```

Now you can call this method without calling `toString`:

```
myMethod(new MyObject());
```